# How do I enable SSL in FSL Fresh Squeezed Limonade PHP Framework via Docker?

Tags: php, rest, docker, microservices

Pulled the yesinteractive/FSL (Fresh Squeezed Limonade) image to develop some quick api microservices from dockerhub which has port 80 enabled by default. There is a 443 listener created but nothing answering on the other end? Anyone ever enable SSL on this image?  If so how do you do it?  Have used this framework on other projects before but first time using it via docker.

Comment: You can see the dockerfile here https://github.com/yesinteractive/fsl has 443 enabled

Answer (score 0):

the Fresh Squeezed Limonade (FSL) php microframework's docker image does not have HTTPS configured only HTTP on port 80. There is a listener in the dockerfile for 443 but that is for furlture enhancements. If you want to enable  SSL you must shell into the container install appropriate packages for Alpine and configure Apache for SSL. The image is Alpine based. We are releasing a CentOS version as well shortly. Check back at https://github.com/yesinteractive/fsl for updates.